# Keycloak OIDC Timeout expired_code

Tags: authentication, keycloak, openid-connect, idp

When I try to login to keycloak through oidc identity provider I get an error related to expired_code, if I disable userinfo the user is taken to a 504 page, if I disable userinfo then this error goes away. In turn, I would like to add that idp takes a very long time to process the request. How can I increase the time?

```
2024-01-15 17:11:20,553 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-17) type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=1bf19c96-43da-4214-b59a-fb8084cb18ed, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=172.26.0.10, error=expired_code, restart_after_timeout=true
```

after refreshing the page 504 I get Page Has Expired after 50 seconds

I increased the login timeout, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was solved by setting ha-proxy and nginx to disconnect after waiting 50 seconds.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).